# Handling nmake errorlevel/return codes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, nmake, errorlevel

I have an nmake-based project which in turn calls the asp compiler, which can throw an error, which nmake seems to recognize:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe' : return code '0x1'
```

However, when I call nmake from within a batch file, the environment variable %ERRORLEVEL% remains set at zero:

```
nmake /NOLOGO
echo BUILD RETURNING: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

If I control-c the nmake task, I do end up getting a non-zero ERRORLEVEL (it's set to 2) so my assumption is that I'm able to catch errors okay, but nmake isn't bubbling up the non-zero exit code from it's task.  Or, at least, I'm mis-trapping it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, please post your batch file so we can see how you trap the error.
Also comment this post so I can read it again.
As a first git, i'd guess something like:

**nmakebatch.cmd** *usual nmake arguments, without /NOLOGO*

```
@echo off
rem Args[x]: nmake arguments
echo.>> %~n0.log
echo %date% %time%>> %~n0.log
echo nmake /NOLOGO %*>> %~n0.log
nmake /NOLOGO %*
echo %errorlevel%>> %~n0.log
```

Is a start for trapping all situations, into a incrementing log, while building.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `exit /b %errorlevel%` in your batch script this will pass the return code back to nmake